# Which .lib has IID___x_ABI_CWindows_CSystem_CProfile_CSystemManufacturers_CISmbiosInformationStatics?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

The windows headers for winrt, specifically
winrt\windows.system.profile.systemmanufacturers.h contain among other things, a reference to:

`EXTERN_C const IID IID___x_ABI_CWindows_CSystem_CProfile_CSystemManufacturers_CISmbiosInformationStatics;`

However as far as I can find, that IID isn't defined in any known linker library. Does anyone happen to know where it is defined?

I'm trying to use this from C to call the winrt apis and getting an unresolved symbol.

Comment: Why do you wonder? What is the *actual* problem you have?

Comment: Using IID___x_ABI_CWindows_CSystem_CProfile_CSystemManufacturers_CISmbiosInformationStatics from C and getting an undefined linker symbol.

Comment: Accessing Windows Runtime types from C is *very* tedious. Have you considered implementing this in C++ instead (using e.g. [C++/WinRT](https://github.com/Microsoft/cppwinrt)), and making it available to your C code by declaring the interface as `extern "C"`?

Comment: I know. I'm parsing the header files for my own compiler; the end result will be a bit more user friendly but I don't know where to find the guid values, programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the MSDN documentation for [SmbiosInformation Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.profile.systemmanufacturers.smbiosinformation) you'll see it's part of the "Windows Desktop Extension SDK" which means it's not defined by default in a project.

You need to add a reference to the Windows Desktop Extension SDK to your application. For a Visual C++ project using C++/CX, you'd add it by using *Add a Reference...* to  Universal Windows -> Extensions -> Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP (pick the version that matches the Target OS version you are using for your project). See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx)

**NOTE:** If you were using [C++/WinRT language projections](https://github.com/Microsoft/cppwinrt) instead of C++/CX, it's all inline in the header `winrt/Windows.System.Profile.SystemManufacturers.h` including the known GUID values as `constexpr` values so you don't need to link with anything special.

> Note that if your application supports anything besides just the Desktop device family, you should guard you use of that class for runtime failure or by checking for support of the `Windows.System.Profile.SystemManufacturers.SystemManufacturersContract`.

Most applications that attempt to use this API will get `E_ACCESSDENIED`. Only special applications listed by the system manufacturer in the system configuration are allowed to use this particular class. See [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180111-00/?p=97775) for what this is all about.

Comment: I know it's not defined by default. That's why I'm asking what does define it, as a search in the winsdk doesn't show it for me.