# Where is the IID of IVpnManagementAgent defined

Tags: c, winapi, windows-runtime

I'm trying to create an object of `IVpnManagementAgent` but I can't seem to find where the IID (`IID___x_ABI_CWindows_CNetworking_CVpn_CIVpnManagementAgent`) of it is defined so I can instance `RoGetActivationFactory` as it seems it requires me a second parameter of `REFIID`.

Also I saw this [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn342867.aspx) but as I'm using C - I can't use `__uuidof`.

Weirdly enough the [msdn sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/wrl/how-to-activate-and-use-a-windows-runtime-component-using-wrl?view=vs-2019) seems to omit this parameter.

The problem is if I compile this code:

```
#include <roapi.h>
#define COBJMACROS
#include <windows.networking.vpn.h>

(main)()
{__x_ABI_CWindows_CNetworking_CVpn_CIVpnManagementAgent *pVpnMan;
    IClassFactory *pCF; RoInitialize(RO_INIT_MULTITHREADED),
        RoGetActivationFactory(0,
            &IID___x_ABI_CWindows_CNetworking_CVpn_CIVpnManagementAgent, 
            &pVpnMan);}
```

Like this: `cl rmousevpn.c /link RuntimeObject.lib windows.networking.lib`

It gives me unresolved:

```
rmousevpn.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol IID___x_ABI_CWindows_CNetworking_CVpn_CIVpnManagementAgent referenced in function main
rmousevpn.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Comment: In the .h, it is _{193696CD-A5C4-4ABE-852B-785BE4CB3E34}_

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55573362/what-library-should-i-link-to-get-proper-definition-of-winrts-extern-c-const-I and https://stackoverflow.com/q/49002774/3501